# Вывести с помощью модуля random данные из двух переменных в одну строку

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Писал код для программы, которая генерирует имя и фамилию, и столкнулся с одной проблемкой:

```
import random
name = ['Alex', 'John', 'Anthony']
surname = ['Williams', 'Jackson', 'Martin']
print(random.choice(name + surname))
```

Интерпретатор выводит только что-то одно из двух переменных, либо только имя, либо только фамилию. Необходимо чтобы интерпретатор выводил имя и фамилию в одну строку.
Ещё пытался сделать так:

```
import random
name = ['Alex', 'John', 'Anthony']
surname = ['Williams', 'Jackson', 'Martin']
fullname = name + surname
print(random.choice(fullname))
```

Но ничего не получилось, проблема остаётся той же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random
name = ['Alex', 'John', 'Anthony']
surname = ['Williams', 'Jackson', 'Martin']
print(f'{random.choice(name)} {random.choice(surname)}')
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Вы меня очень выручили!

Comment: Обратите внимание на причину. Вы для рандомизатора одну выборку оставляли вместо двух. Он и не мог по-другому.